# How to create a individual Visual Studio short cut?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I would like to have a shortcut for the Documentation like this:

```
/**
*
*@param 
*/
```

How can i create such a shortcut in Visual Studio ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the following C# command in [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) and assign a shortcut to it:

```
EnvDTE.TextSelection ts = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection as EnvDTE.TextSelection;
ts.Text =
@"/**
*
*@param 
*/";
```